# What can I do with 10Base2 cable?

Tags: ethernet

So I have about 10 meters of 10Base2 cable with terminators laying around which I have not thrown away because, who knows?
Well in 25 years (gosh) I have not found a use for it. It is time to throw it in the recycling bin or find a new home for it. What can it used for and who can use it?

Comment: You're probably like me and you hate to throw stuff away that is still in good working condition.  I've kept old stuff for years, thinking I might use it again.  I never did.  My advice is to look for a place that you can drop off electronic waste (e-waste), and do so.

Comment: I'd be more interested in hearing the technical answer. What were the properties of 10Base2 cable, is it usable for other technologies such as MoCA or plain old TV stuff, etc.